# Does the Preview app have a freehand pen/pencil tool?

Tags: macos, preview, image-editing

The Preview app has markup / annotate tools like rectangle, oval, line, text, speech bubble, thought bubble.  Is there a pen or pencil tool that lets you draw lines in a freehand way?

(I'm using Preview version 7.0 (826.4) in OS X Mavericks 10.9.5)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just as a side note: there _is_ a freehand sketch tool under OS X 10.10, though this may not be the prime reason to upgrade for you.

Comment: An additional (side) note: if you are simply looking for a freehand tool, and don't mind discarding Preview, you might give [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) a try. Skim has an excellent freehand drawing tool.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, Preview in OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) has a freehand tool.  Access it within Preview from the "Markup Toolbar" icon of the .JPG or .PDF file you have open.

> [image: OS X Preview tool "markup toolbar" icon]

When you click on that icon, the Markup toolbar appears, and the freehand "sketch" tool is the 3rd icon from the left, in blue in the image below.

> [image: OS X Preview tool "sketch" tool]

and it offers a smoothing option as well as a freehand mode.

Comment: Thanks @Charles_Lindsay!  Alas, I'm still on Mavericks, reluctant to switch to Yosemite, so I don't have the freehand tool.  Nice to know it is in Yosemite though.  Maybe one of these days I'll take the risk and upgrade to Yosemite.

Comment: Any way to make Preview suggest replacements but not automatically replace? So to make it keep the originaö drawing?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth That's the most annoying feature ever. It suggests some shape 90% of the time and every time it does I have to change it back. Not once have I ever wanted it to change the original drawing. It makes annotating PDFs really painful because I have to go and click a button after every stroke. I've searched and searched but haven't found a solution other than using a different program.